# javascript: Requires upload file”,“type”:“OAuthException Facebook user already registered

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, image-uploading

I am using the Facebook JavaScript SDK to upload photos to facebook timeline. 
Initially I used this code and it worked:

```
<script language="javascript">
   function test() {
      var message = document.getElementById('txtMessage').value;
      FB.login(function (response) {
         if (response.authResponse) {
            var access_token = FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
            FB.api('https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos', 'post', {
               message: message,
               status: 'success',
               access_token: access_token,
               url: 'http://dotnetspeaks.com/xyz.jpg'
            }, function (response) {
                  if (!response || response.error) {
                     alert('Error occured:' + response);
                  } else {
                     alert('Successfully posted on wall.');
                  }
               });
         } else {
            alert('Interrupted.');
         }
      }, { scope: 'user_photos,photo_upload,publish_stream,offline_access' });
   }
</script>
```

I have added FB.init above all.
This code worked once but then gave me the error that "user is already signed in".
Then I found FB.getLoginStatus() function to check if the user is logged in or not. I changed to code to below

```
<script language="javascript">
   function test() {
       FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
           if (response.status === 'connected') {       
             var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
             var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
             FB.api('https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos/uploaded', 'post', {
                   message: "hii",
                   status: 'success',
                   access_token: accessToken,
                   url: "images/brave_t.jpg"
                }, function (response) {
                      if (!response || response.error) {
                         alert('Error occured:' + response);
                      } else {
                         alert('Successfully posted on wall.');
                      }
                   },{scope: 'publish_actions,photo_upload'});
           } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
             // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
             // but has not authenticated your app
           } else {
             // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
           }
          });
   }
</script>
```

I added the scope field to check if that works as *"{scope: 'publish_actions,photo_upload'}"* but that too didn't work. I am repeatedly geeting this error : *"message: "(#324) Requires upload file"* .

Please help me to resolve this.
I want to upload image to the Facebook timeline
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL has to be absolute, you are trying to use a relative path:

```
url: "images/brave_t.jpg"
```

In the first code part, you are doing it in a correct way:

```
url: 'http://dotnetspeaks.com/xyz.jpg'
```

Btw, there is no `photo_upload` permission, `publish_actions` is all you need. If you need more information about FB.login and FB.getLoginStatus, take a look at this article: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/